# Drawing line overlays over edges of CIImage

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, cifilter, metal-performance-shaders

I have a custom Metal CIKernel that displays edges on the image in red color. In the shader, I do a convolution to compute Sobel gradient and then return the color as red or original color. But I believe there should be a way to do the same using builtin CIFilters or MPS shaders. But how?

```
extern "C" half4 drawEdges (coreimage::sampler inputImage, 
                             coreimage::destination dest)
 {
  float2 destCoord = dest.coord();
  float2 srcCoord = inputImage.coord();
  half4 color =  half4(inputImage.sample(srcCoord)); 

  float2 m11Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(-1.0,+1.0));

  half3 m11 = half3(inputImage.sample(m11Coord).rgb);   

  float2 m12Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(0.0,+1.0));
  half3 m12 = half3(inputImage.sample(m12Coord).rgb); 
  float2 m13Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(+1.0,+1.0));
  half3 m13 = half3(inputImage.sample(m13Coord).rgb);  

  float2 m21Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(-1.0,0.0));
  half3 m21 = half3(inputImage.sample(m21Coord).rgb); 

  float2 m23Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(+1.0,0.0));
  half3 m23 = half3(inputImage.sample(m23Coord).rgb);

  float2 m31Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(-1.0,-1.0));
  half3 m31 = half3(inputImage.sample(m31Coord).rgb);

  float2 m32Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(0.0,-1.0));
  half3 m32 = half3(inputImage.sample(m32Coord).rgb); 

  float2 m33Coord = inputImage.transform(destCoord + float2(+1.0,+1.0));
  half3 m33 = half3(inputImage.sample(m33Coord).rgb);

  half3 m31m13 = m31 - m13;
  half3 m11m33 = m33 - m11;
  half3 m32m12 = m32 - m12;
  half3 m21m23 = m21 - m23;
  half3 H = m32m12 + m32m12 + m11m33 + m31m13;
  half3 V = m21m23 + m21m23 - m11m33 + m31m13;

  half3 sobel = sqrt(H*H+V*V);
  half sobelLength = length(sobel);

  if (sobelLength > 0.9) {
    half4 redColor = half4(0.5h, 0.h, 0.0, 1.0);
    color = redColor;
 }

  return half4(color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a filter chain like this would roughly do the same:

```
  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │                                                                           ▼
input ───► CIPhotoEffectNoire ───► CIEdges ───► CIBlendWithMask ───► CISourceOverCompositing ───► output
                                                       ▲
                      CIImage(color: .red) ────────────┘
```

Note that I converted the input to grayscale using `CIPhotoEffectNoire` here because `CIEdges` actually returns the sobel edges in color, which is harder to color in with red.

Comment: How do I get color intensity from grayscale image above, if I want to smoothen the output by blending edges with red depending on edge sharpness.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432735/metal-core-image-sampler-pixel-format) question as well.

Comment: The output of `CIEdges` should already reflect the sharpness/steepness of the edge, i.e., sharper edges should produce higher "color" values. When using this as a mask for blending a red image over a black background, you should get stronger red where stronger edges are.

Comment: Great, but the problem is how to detect color (intensity) values in RGB space that work across color gamuts?  Metal Core Image samplers do not support single dimensional gray space (unlike Metal shaders where one can specify formats such as .r8). In the absense of it, I rely on computing dot product with `(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722)` which works for BT.709 space. Will the same thing produce accurate results for BT.2020, I am not sure.