# Metal Core Image Sampler pixel format

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, metalkit

I have this Metal code that I want to translate to Metal CoreImage kernel.

```
    fragment half4 fragmentShaderThreshold ( MappedVertex in [[ stage_in ]],
                                 texture2d<half, access::sample> inputTexture [[ texture(0) ]]
                                 )
  {
  constexpr sampler s(s_address::clamp_to_edge, t_address::clamp_to_edge, min_filter::linear, mag_filter::linear);

  half3 rgb = inputTexture.sample(s, in.textureCoordinate).rgb; 
  half3 weights = half3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722);

  float intensity = dot(rgb, weights);

  if (intensity >= 0.95) {
     rgb = half3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  } else if (intensity <= 0.05) {
     rgb = half3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }

    return half4(rgb, 1.h);
 }
```

To do the same in Metal Core Image kernel, I think this is something that can be done with builtin filters. Because builtin filters can work in variety of color spaces such as BT.2020. Please comment on how this can be achieved using builtin filters.

If it is not possible using builtin filters, I was thinking of converting the image to grayscale and read the intensity (gray value) in Metal Core Image kernel. It looks like Metal Core Image samplers support only RGB based pixel formats (unlike Metal where textures can have pixel format such as r8). Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple built-in filter for converting an image to grayscale. `CIPhotoEffectNoir` does it, but it uses a color cube / look up table under the hood, and it's not documented how it is defined.

You could probably use `CIColorMatrix` to do the first part of the kernel:

```swift
let colorMatrixFilter = CIFilter.colorMatrix()
let lumaCoefficients = CIVector(x: 0.2126, y: 0.7152, z: 0.0722, w: 0.0)
colorMatrixFilter.rVector = lumaCoefficients
colorMatrixFilter.bVector = lumaCoefficients
colorMatrixFilter.gVector = lumaCoefficients
```

You could further adjust the luma coefficients to match the color space you are working in, though Core Image converts everything to extended linear sRGB by default, so these should be correct.

For the intensity thresholding you could probably use some clever combination of `CIColorThreshold` and `CIBlendWithMask`, but honestly, I would write a simple custom color kernel for that. It should also be faster at runtime.

And yes, Core Image always works with 4-channel textures. In a custom kernel that only produces a single-channel output, you usually write the same value in all 3 color channels. Alternatively, you can also specify a single-channel `outputPixelFormat` such as `.Rh` when initializing your kernel with `init(functionName: String, fromMetalLibraryData: Data, outputPixelFormat: CIFormat)`, but CI will swizzle it back to a 4-channel image anyway before passing it as input to the next filter (unless that's a processor that explicitly works with single-channel inputs, but that's rare).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are couple of doubts here. First, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontextoption/1437728-workingcolorspace) for `workingColorSpace` says " 128 bits-per-pixel, linear light, premultiplied RGBA floating-point values that use the GenericRGB color space". Is that same as extended linear sRGB? Second, the thresholds for intensity will change if BT2020 image is converted to sRGB. It may be 2.0 or 5.0 instead of 0.95, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, that documentation is very old and outdated. It was written in a time when Core Image was a Mac-only framework. I'm very positive that the default working space is linear light, extended (values outside of 0..1 allowed), premultiplied sRGB with 16-bit float (64 bit-per-pixel) working format (on iOS).

Comment: And you are right, luma would be computed differently for BT.2020. I think you could convert the input to the BT.2020 color space before passing it to `CIColorMatrix` using `image.matchedFromWorkingSpace(to: bt2020ColorSpace)`, and adapting the luma coefficients accordingly.

Comment: My input is already BT.2020. But how to know luma coefficients for the same?

Comment: One more thing, if the workingColorSpace is sRGB and the output is passed to  MTKView (with EDR parameters set on CAMetalLayer accordingly) for display, I hope MTKView displays full range of BT.2020 colors. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.2020_conversion) is correct, the coefficients for BT.2020 should be `(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722)`. And yes, if you set up the view to display in that color space, it would work. The working space is _extended_ sRGB, so even values outside of regular sRGB will be retained.

Comment: So the MTKView would once again do colorSpace conversion from extended linear sRGB to HLG 2100 if CAMetalLayer colorspace is set to `.itur_2100_HLG` for HDR. I tried setting `outputColorSpace` of `CIContext` to be NSNull() which tells CoreImage to do no color conversion on the output and it works. But I can not set `workingColorSpace` to HLG2100. It gives me errors - *CIContext kCIContextWorkingColorSpace must be [NSNull null], or a CGColorSpaceRef with kCGColorSpaceModelRGB that supports output.*

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77439913/cicontext-colorspace-for-mtkview) to question  for the above comment.

Comment: FYI, the correct coefficients for BT.2020 to calculate luminance are `(0.2627, 0.6780, 0.0593)`