# CIContext workingColorSpace for MTKView

Tags: ios, core-image, metalkit, mtkview, cametallayer

I have the following two contexts:

```
 private lazy var firstContext: CIContext  = {
    let options:[CIContextOption:Any] = [CIContextOption.cacheIntermediates: false];
    
    return CIContext(mtlDevice: self.device!, options: options)
}()

 private lazy var secondContext: CIContext  = {
    let options:[CIContextOption:Any] = [CIContextOption.cacheIntermediates: false, CIContextOption.outputColorSpace: NSNull(), CIContextOption.workingColorSpace: NSNull()];
    
    return CIContext(mtlDevice: self.device!, options: options)
}()

 public var useFirstContext = true

private var context: CIContext {

    return useFirstContext ? firstContext : secondContext
}
```

And my `MTKView` is configured as follows:

```
    metalLayer = self.layer as? CAMetalLayer
    
    metalLayer?.wantsExtendedDynamicRangeContent = true
    metalLayer.colorspace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.itur_2100_HLG)
    
    colorPixelFormat = .bgr10a2Unorm
```

When I render incoming pixel buffers using ciContext, I see different outputs on `MTKView` with the two contexts. There is no filter chain configured, except for rescaling and transforming CIImage. Why is the output different with the two contexts when incoming buffers are in the same color space? Here is the drawing code:

```
 func drawCIImage(_ ciImage:CIImage?) {
    guard let image = ciImage,
        let currentDrawable = currentDrawable,
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
        else {
            return
    }

    let drawableSize = self.drawableSize
    
    let scaleX = drawableSize.width / image.extent.width
    let scaleY = drawableSize.height / image.extent.height
    let scaledImage = image.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY))
    let filteredImage = scaledImage
    
   
    let destination = CIRenderDestination(width: Int(drawableSize.width),
                                          height: Int(drawableSize.height),
                                          pixelFormat: self.colorPixelFormat,
                                          commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                                          mtlTextureProvider: { () -> MTLTexture in
                                             return currentDrawable.texture
    })
    
    _ = try? context.startTask(toRender: filteredImage, to: destination)
    
    commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

Comment: I think this is more or less a duplicate of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77455074/cicontext-options-for-hdr-display/77455872), right? I answered you there.

Comment: @FrankRupprecht Yes it is duplicate, though I thought this question wording may have been ambigious.