# CIContext options for HDR display

Tags: ios, core-image, metalkit, mtkview

I have two CIContexts configured with the following options:

```
let options1:[CIContextOption:Any] = [CIContextOption.cacheIntermediates: false, CIContextOption.outputColorSpace: NSNull(), CIContextOption.workingColorSpace: NSNull()];

let options2:[CIContextOption:Any] = [CIContextOption.cacheIntermediates: false];
```

And an MTKView with CAMetalLayer configured with HDR output.

```
    metalLayer = self.layer as? CAMetalLayer
    
    metalLayer?.wantsExtendedDynamicRangeContent = true
    metalLayer.colorspace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.itur_2100_HLG)
    
    colorPixelFormat = .bgr10a2Unorm
```

The two context options produce different outputs when input is in BT.2020 pixel buffers. But I believe the outputs shouldn't be different. Because the first option simply disables color management. The second one performs intermediate buffer calculations in sRGB extended linear color space and then converts those buffers to BT.2020 color space in the output. Is the output different because of loss of information in the intermediate step?

Finally, which of the options is correct in displaying HDR sample buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your last question first: Yes, this is a valid and good way to set up the `MTKView` for displaying HDR content. But, as you pointed out, you also need to tell the `MTLView` to tone-map the EDR values to the display's brightness range by setting `metalLayer.edrMetadata = .hlg`.

Alternatively, I found that the following setup also works for displaying EDR content:

```swift
metalLayer.wantsExtendedDynamicRangeContent = true
metalLayer.colorspace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.extendedLinearSRGB)
colorPixelFormat = .rgba16Float
```

It seems the view knows how to tone-map extended linear EDR values to its display automatically in this case – no need for setting `edrMetadata`.

---

The rest I would like to split into two topics:

##### Working Color Space

You are correct: When setting `CIContextOption.workingColorSpace: NSNull()`, you effectively disable Core Image's automatic color management. However, I would only advise doing that when the following is the case:

- You know what the color space of the input is,
- you don't apply any built-in filters (as they assume their input to be in CI's default working color space), and
- you configured the output to be in the same color space as the input.

So in your case, if you never want to apply filters in your pipeline, you are probably ok disabling the color matching by setting the working space to `NSNull()`. This would even save a bit of processing time, though not very much, as color space conversion is rather inexpensive.

In most scenarios, I would recommend not touching the `workingColorSpace` option and letting CI decide what to use.

##### Output Color Space

Unfortunately, the `CIContextOption.outputColorSpace` is very misleading. It doesn't seem to be used in almost all use cases – at least I haven't seen any effects so far.

That's because usually you either

- pass the output color space to a render API of `CIContext` directly, like in `createCGImage(_ image:, from fromRect:, format:, colorSpace:)`,
- or the render destination defines the color space.

And the second point is the crux here. I believe you are rendering into the view using the `CIRenderDestination` API, probably defined like this:

```swift
let destination = CIRenderDestination(width: Int(drawableSize.width),
                                      height: Int(drawableSize.height),
                                      pixelFormat: self.colorPixelFormat,
                                      commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                                      mtlTextureProvider: { () -> MTLTexture in
                                          return currentDrawable.texture
                                      })
```

The problem here is that a `CIRenderDestination` can't fully infer the color space of the target on its own (it usually defaults to sRGB). That's why you have to set it explicitly.

And here you know that the view is expecting the drawable texture to contain pixel data in `itur_2100_HLG`. So either set that directly, or simply set it to the view's color space:

```swift
destination.colorSpace = metalLayer.colorspace
```

Then Core Image will know to which color space to convert to when rendering into the destination.

With this change, there should now be no more difference between color management turned off (`CIContextOption.workingColorSpace: NSNull()`) and on.

Comment: *So either set that directly, or simply set it to the view's color space:* . Setting `destination.colorSpace` works, but not view's colorspace via CAMetalLayer (as it was already set in the sample code above).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "set the destination's color space to that of the view's `CAMetalLayer`" (as the code above shows).

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77460758/metal-core-image-kernels-for-image-statistics) important question as well.

Comment: Frank, I see that this method of display is resulting in overexposed highlights. There is something that requires fixing.

Comment: Ok, I see `edrMetadata` needs to be set as well on `CAMetalLayer`!

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. If `edrMetadata` is not set "the system doesn’t perform any tone mapping of data prior to passing it on to the display. Values above the maximum may be clipped." (from the docs).

Comment: I amended the first part of my answer with your insights.

Comment: There is very little documentation about extended linear spaces (sRGB or itur_2020). Will using these spaces faithfully represent all colors in the BT2020 gamut?

Comment: Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472297/metal-core-image-kernel-workingcolorspace) for you that arises after pondering over thoughts generated from your answer.