# Metal Core Image kernels for Image statistics

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, cifilter, metalkit

I am currently computing histogram, waveform, and vectoroscope using Accelerate and Metal shaders. This code is for 8-bit SDR pixel buffers and it works. I want to rewrite them using Core Image so that they can work for both 10-bit HDR & SDR buffers.

1. Accelerate works very well for histogram for 8-bit images. However it does not support 10bit YCbCr pixel buffers. CoreImage supports it but it is unclear how to grab raw histogram data from the `CIAreaHistogram` output so as to display it using CoreGraphics or MTKView. The builtin histogram `CIHistogramDisplayFilter` to display histogram has less flexibility. I also want histogram of luminance as well apart from rgb.
2. I use `atomic_fetch_add_explicit` in Metal shaders to compute statistics such as Waveform and vectoroscope. It seems Metal core image kernels have no support for atomics. Is there any way to do the same in CoreImage?

Answer (score 2):

For the histogram, I think you have two options:

1. You can write your own histogram visualization kernel, similar to what `CIHistogramDisplayFilter` does. You could pass it an RGB and a luminance histogram and visualize them to your liking.
2. You calculate the histograms (e.g., with `CIAreaHistogram`) and render the result into a bitmap buffer. You can then read the bin values from that buffer and visualize them custom UI components, e.g., using SwiftUI. In our [CoreImageExtensions library on Github](https://github.com/DigitalMasterpieces/CoreImageExtensions#image-value-access) we also have some convenience APIs for reading values from a `CIImage` that might ease this process.

Concerning the atomics: If you already have a working Metal implementation for those statistics, I would recommend you write a `CIImageProcessorKernel` around it. It's made for this exact purpose: including custom image processors into a Core Image pipeline. Especially working with Metal is very convenient, as you already get a Metal device, textures, and a command buffer to work with.

---

Some details on `CIAreaHistogram`:

The output of the `CIAreaHistogram` filter is an image that is 1 pixel tall and as wide as specified by `inputCount`.
`inputCount` specifies how many bins you want to have in your histogram. Each pixel in the output contains *the percentage* of pixels that fall into the corresponding bin, separated by channels.

So for instance, if you set `inputCount` to 2 (so two bins), and the output image looks like this:
`[(0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.0), (0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0)]`, that means that 30 % of all red values fall into the first bin and 70 % into the second bin; 60 % of all green values in the first bin, 40 % in the second bin; and so on.

Notice that the values per channel across all bins will add up to 1.0 by default. You can change that, however, using the `inputScale` parameter, to multiply all values with a factor. It can make sense, especially when you have a large `inputCount`, to increase the `inputScale` to not lose precision due to potentially very small values per bin.

Comment: The bin values that are output of `CIAreaHistogram`, it's not clear what is the scale of values. For instance when using `vImage` API, I can get integer frequency count for every color value. I then find the maximum value of frequencies and them divide each frequency value by maximum value to normalise it to [0,1] range. It's not clear how one can do the same with Core Image histogram output.

Comment: I amended my answer with some more details.

Comment: So multiplying these numbers by number of pixels in image will give the absolute count of frequency, correct?

Comment: Also, if the input pixel format of pixel buffer embedded in CIImage is YCbCr, I believe core image will do pixel format conversion to RGBA before executing the histogram kernel. This would fetch histogram for RGBA, but what about Luma histogram? `MPSImageHistogram` can compute luma histogram if we pass the Y texture as input with pixel format of .r8 (for 8 bit image). Core Image seems to have no option for this.

Comment: Yes, the numbers in the histogram represent a percentage value per bin (if `inputScale` is 1). When you multiply by the number of pixels, you should get absolute values (just be mindful of float precision here, as CI on iOS only uses 16-bit half float).

Comment: Yes, CI only works with RGBA and will convert to that if necessary. However, `CIAreaHistogram` will simply compute the histogram of the input image. So you could write a simple filter for converting RGB to luma and pass the result to `CIAreaHistogram` to get the luma histogram.